# Transform/Manipulate Value Before Displaying in GridViewColumn of ListView control (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my XAML, I have the following `GridViewColumn`

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Date Added" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DateAdded}" Width="80"/>
```

The binding works as expected: there is a column named `DateAdded` in my SQL table and it has a Unix Timestamp value per each record. When the window loads, it displays a `ListView` with all columns, but the *Date Added* column has the actual timestamp (`1516596663`, etc.)

How can I transform the timestamp value (i.e. `1516596663`) to something like `January 22, 2018 4:51:03 AM`?

The way I setup my `ListView` on load is as follows--

```
crHistoryList.ItemsSource = _db.recordHistories.ToList();
dataListView = crHistoryList;
```

(`crHistoryList` is the name of my `ListView`)

**Please Note:**
I am not asking *how* to convert from UNIX Timestamp to human-readable date/time... but rather: where to input the logic of conversion AND then how to bind that, so it displays the transformed value and not the value retrieved from the database.

Comment: If `StringFormat` is not enough for some reason, use a `Converter` (but first try the format as answered by Marc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can provide you a two step solution:

1. Create a converter which converts your unix timestamp to DateTime
2. Format your DateTime with the use of `StringFormat` that will give you:

`DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DateAdded, StringFormat={}{MM/dd/YYYY}, Converter={StaticResource UnixToDateTime}"`

Have a look here how to create a converter: [click](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

and here, how to format your DateTime: [click](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/datetime-xaml-syntax)

Comment: Referenced link does not point to anywhere... also, by adding `StringFormat` does display any value (not even the timestamp)

Comment: I chose to create a converter... but I keep getting `The resource "UnixTimestampConverter" could not be resolved.` (I created a new .cs file called UnixTimestampConverter.cs) I have run "Clean Solution" as well as "Rebuild Solution"

Comment: @Rushikumar you have to create the resource for the converter. Have a look here http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/value-conversion-with-ivalueconverter/

Comment: Perfect; thank you for the pointers... creating a `Converter` did the trick; I will post my (full code) solution... it might help someone

Answer (score 1):

In the event someone is in the same boat, and would like to see (by code) how to do this, following the suggestions of @Marc & @grek40 of building a `converter`

#### In your `.xaml` file

Add the following after `<Window x:Class=...`

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:UnixTimestampConverter x:Key="utsConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Where `UnixTimestampConverter` is the name of your class file.... `utsConverter` is merely a name for the class file, which shall be referenced in the `DisplayMemberBinding` as follows--

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Date Added" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DateAdded, Converter={StaticResource utsConverter}}" Width="80"/>
```

#### Next, create the `UnixTimestampConverter.cs` file

- Because this file will implement the `IValueConverter` interface, add the following `using` directive to this class file:

  `using System.Windows.Data;`
- Next, implement the interface and within the `Convert` method, the *transformation* will occur... Full code for the `UnixTimestampConverter.cs` is shown below--

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace myProject
{
    class UnixTimestampConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                System.DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
                dateTime = dateTime.AddSeconds(System.Convert.ToDouble(value)).ToLocalTime();
                return dateTime;
            }
            else
            {
                return String.Empty;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Good Converter related resources--

1. [ValueConverters](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html)
2. [Value conversion with IValueConverter](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/value-conversion-with-ivalueconverter/) --- thanks @Marc

Answer (score 0):

As Marc said you must do these steps:
at first add Converter Class to your project:

```
 public class TimeStampToDate : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            double unixTimeStamp = System.Convert.ToDouble(value);
            System.DateTime result = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
            result = result.AddSeconds(unixTimeStamp).ToLocalTime();
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

in the second step add namespace of the converter class in your xaml file like this:

```
xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:Plugin.Converters"
```

third step add your converter as resource in your xaml file:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>           
        <Converters:TimeStampToDate x:Key="TimeStampToDate"/>            
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

in the end you need change some part of your code:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Date Added" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=DateAdded,Converter={StaticResource TimeStampToDate}}" Width="80"/>
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks Leila; I didn't need to add any thing under `UserControl.Resources` or `ResourceDictionary` --- simply adding to `Window.Resources` was sufficient... is there any downside to that? Or must it be how you specified, in the `XAML` file? (and if so, why?)